# Using Gitlab Multi project pipelines how can u run a specific job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Using multi project pipelines I want to run a specific job. Under deploy I have CI - PVT - Staging - Prod

I wish to deploy from a separate project simply Deploy Staging none of the other deploy stages.

I do have a paid for Gitlab so triggering etc. is enabled.

Is this possible please?